# Allowing optional prefix in url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am using wordpress and I have the following URL

```
http://www.example.com/product/sony-xperia/
```

What I am trying to achieve is if I add `fr` after the base url like the example below, I want to display the same content as I can see for the url above.

```
http://www.example.com/fr/product/sony-xperia/
```

Could you please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: so the .com/product will be English and .com/fr/product will be French?

Comment: I need to display the content in English for both the urls for now.

Comment: You will need to use WP rewrite API for this instead of Apache rewrite rules.

Comment: @anubhava Could you please tell me how to achieve this using WP rewrite's API ?

Comment: [Will this help?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do it. I wrote the following piece of code in my function.php file and it worked.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() 
{   
  add_rewrite_rule('^fr/product/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?product=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```